# Cut Face out of an taken picture for later use?

Tags: android

I tried to find a project with which I can cut a face out of a picture for later use.

The idea is that I am building an app in which you can insert your face in an avatar. I thought about taking a picture of myself and cut the face out with something to insert this picture in an avatar.

What am I searching for? Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you still working on this? I have written [an application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=edu.usf.eng.pie.avatars4change) which does exactly this. The source code is [here](https://github.com/7yl4r/AvatarWallpaper), but it is poorly written and bloated with unrelated features. I can better segment out and document this part if you have use for it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android provides functionality for face detection.

You can find it at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.Face.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: I found this before. With this I know where the face is. But how can I cut it out and transfer it in a new image?

Comment: You need to 1) save camera image to a file. 2) Crop the image (according to coordinates from `FaceDetector`). Both operations can be easily searched about. Good luck